# Django: want to loop through _set for pk values only

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to filter my template values with the detail view PK. I have a detail view for my employee. I wish to display my employee's subjects, where I then wish to filter the subjects with the evaluations that have been made for the subject.

I've gotten so far that I can show my subject names, and show all the evaluations for each subject. However, I don't want to show ALL of them I only want to show the ones that exist for the current employee (detailView PK). As you can see in my template, I'm using _set to make the relation, but I have no clue on how to filter the PK into that equation.

**Example, what I want:**

Subject 1:

Evaluationname - employee Johnny

Evaluationname - employee Johnny

**Example, what I currently have:**

Subject 1:

Evaluationname - employee Johnny

Evaluationname - employee Chris

I don't want Chris's evaluation, I only wish to filter the primary key, so in this case Johnny's evaluations.

**Template**

```
{% for subject in subject_list %}
    <a href="">{{ subject.subejctname }}</a>
    {% for evaluation in subject.evaluation_set.all %}
        <div>
        <p>{{ evaluering.ma }} | {{ evaluering.ma.firstname }} | {{ evaluering.ma.lastname }}</p>
        </div>
    {% empty %}
        <p>No evaluations founds.</p>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**View**

```
class EmployeeDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'evalsys/employee/alle_employees_eval.html'
    model = Employee

    # Uses employee PK to make a detail view
    def view_employee_with_pk(self, pk=None):
        if pk:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=pk)
        else:
            employee = self.employee
        args = {'employee': employee, }
        return render(self, 'evalsys/employee/alle_employees_eval.html', args)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailViewDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['subject_list'] = Subject.objects.all()
        return context
```

**Subject Model**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   subjectname = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Indtast navnet på faget.")
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**Evaluation model**

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   employee_num = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   subjectname = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**Employee model**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
   employee_num = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
   firstname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
   lastname = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
   subjectname = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reverse relationships (`subject.evaluation_set`) can be [prefetched](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related), this is a technique for reducing the number of database queries made when you access the reverse relationship for many objects in a queryset. When using the following queryset, when you access `subject.evaluation_set.all` it will not perform an additional DB access as the result has already been cached on each instance

```
Subject.objects.all().prefetch_related('evaluation_set')
```

This cached result can be modified by using [Prefetch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) objects. Using these you can limit the contents of `subject.evaluation_set.all` to only contain the result that you want

```
Subject.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'evaluation_set',
        queryset=Evaluation.objects.filter(employee=self.employee)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I knew I needed some extra filtering but did not know about prefetch. I don't quite understand where this logic should be placed in my code? I assume in the view?

Comment: I figured it out, added it to the context and it worked with how my template currently looks. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Your model structure is confusing. Are you able to detail the relationship between employee, subject and evaluation?? You have mentioned you wish to display an employee's subjects, but via your model structure, an employee can have only one subject, as employee is related to the subject by a foreign key.

Below I have suggested some changes to your model names and your model structure so it might make more sense to retrieve your evaluations in the template. Feel free to ask questions about your model design as that is crucial to design your views, templates, etc.

Also please refer here for model naming conventions
[Django Foreign Key Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey)
[Django Model Coding Style (PEP8)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style)

**Subject Model**

```
class Subject(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Indtast navnet på 
    faget.")
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

**Employee Model**

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    employee_num = models.IntegerField(help_text="Indtast medarbejderens MA-nummer. (F.eks 123456)")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens fornavn.")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, help_text="Indtast medarbejderens efternavn.")
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='employee', through='Evaluation')
```

**Evaluation Model**

```
class Evaluation(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=50)
   employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So the assumption, is an employee can have different subjects and the mapping is defined via a through model using many-to-many.

Your DetaiView can then just be

```
class EmployeeDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'evalsys/employee/alle_employees_eval.html'
    model = Employee

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailViewDetailView, 
          self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['evaluations'] = Evaluation.objects.filter(employee=self.object)
        return context
```

**Template**

```
{% for evaluation in evaluations %}
    <a href="">{{ evaluation.subject.subject_name }}</a>
    <p>{{ evaluation.name }} | {{ evaluation.employee.first_name }} |
       {{evaluation.employee.last_name }}</p>
{% empty %}
    <p>No evaluations founds.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth reply. It makes  alot of sense. I have done what you kindly suggested, and I now have the self.object for the employees evaluations, but I don't have them distinctly. Each evaluation is "stamped" with a subject name, but how would I go about showing only the name of the subject once and all evaluations under that one subject?

Comment: You need to determine the relationship between employee, subject and evaluation. If you want all evaluations for a subject, you need to filter out evaluations with the subject id and you will have your resultset.